# Merge several confusion matrix with xtable

Tags: r, r-markdown, confusion-matrix, xtable

I have trained several models and want to summarise their performance with three confusion matrix.  **What I want to do is to combine three different confusion matrix into one table using `xtable`**. I want to combine table 1, 2 and 3.  See an example below using XGBoost.

```
require(xgboost)
require(xtable)
require(caTools)
require(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)

# Loading data
x1 = c(rnorm(10000, 0,1), rnorm(10000,3,1))
x2 = rnorm(1000)
x3 = rnorm(1000)
class= factor(rep(0:1, each=10000))

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1, x2, x3, class))

# Preparing target variable
df$class <- as.numeric(df$class)
df$class <- df$class -1

# Creating a hold-out data
train <- sample.split(df$class, SplitRatio = 0.70)
train.df <- subset(df, train == TRUE)
test.df <- subset(df, train == FALSE)

#Labels. 
labels.train <- train.df[c('class')]
labels.test <- test.df[c('class')]

# Dropping target variable.
train.df <- train.df %>%
  dplyr::select(-class)

test.df <- test.df %>%
  dplyr::select(-class)

# Converting to appropiate format. 
train <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(train.df), label = as.matrix(labels.train))
test <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(test.df), label = as.matrix(labels.test))

watchlist <- list(eval = test, train = train)

# Running the model
model <- xgb.train(data=train,
                   watchlist = watchlist,
                   nround = 1000, 
                   early_stopping_rounds = 25,                 
                   objective = "binary:logistic")

# Predictions
pred <- predict(model, test)

# Evaluating the p-distribution. 
hist(pred)

# Confusion matrix
table1 <- table(pred > 0.5, labels.test$class)
table2 <- table(pred > 0.25, labels.test$class)
table3 <- table(pred > 0.75, labels.test$class)

print(xtable(table1, caption = 'Threshhold = 50%'))
print(xtable(table2, caption = 'Threshhold = 25%'))
print(xtable(table3, caption = 'Threshhold = 75%'))
```

The outcome now looks like this

[image]

but I want it to look something like this

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you want? The title of your question is "Confusion matrix in Rmarkdown" and the closest you get to a question in your post is "So I want to combine table 1, 2 and 3."   Are you just looking for information about how to make a table in R Markdown?

Comment: So I suppose let me be more specific myself. There are many conceivable ways to combine this information into one table. What do you mean when you say you want to combine them? Combine them how? What _specifically_ do you want your _output_ to look like?

Comment: @duckmayr Sorry, I realized I was a bit unclear. Is it more clear for you now?

Comment: Yes, much better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution using `kable()` from `knitr`, `add_header_above()` and `kable_styling()` from `kableExtra` is next. Add this code after creating the confusion matrices:

```
#Format table
t1 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table1)
t2 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table2)
t3 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table3)
#Bind
tm <- cbind(t1,t2,t3)
```

Then next code produces the output you want:

```
kable(tm,"latex",longtable =T,booktabs =T,caption ="Longtable")%>%
  add_header_above(c(" ","p=50%"=2,"p=25%"=2,"p=75%"=2))%>%
  kable_styling(latex_options =c("repeat_header"))
```

I have run the previous code in a `rmarkdown` document and the result is next:

[image]

You must also add libraries `knitr` and `kableExtra` to your code.

Comment: Thank you @Duck, exactly what I was looking for. Just one minor follow-up question: _How do I add a label for the reference values (FALSE/TRUE) where it says "True/reference value"?_

Comment: @ecl You can create a new dataframe like `rnames <- data.frame(`True/reference value`=rownames(tm))` then use `rownames(tm)<-NULL` and finally `tm2 <- cbind(rnames,tm)`. That should alleviate your issue!